# how to convert dutch string dates?

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to convert a string variable with Dutch dates into a date variable
some example values of the original variable (date.string) : "18 sep. 2016", "29 mei 2014", "7 mrt. 2016" I tried:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$dta.string, format = "%d %h %Y", locale = "dutch")
```

clearly I'm making a mistake since I only get NA's returned in my new column, some one any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380514/month-language-in-the-as-date-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lubridate::dmy` has a `locale` parameter where you can specify what locale to evaluate the strings with without changing your actual locale. It also cuts through inconsistent separators, which is handy:

```
lubridate::dmy(c("18 sep. 2016", "29 mei 2014", "7 mrt. 2016"), locale = 'nl_NL.UTF-8')
## [1] "2016-09-18" "2014-05-29" "2016-03-07"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do

```
df <- data.frame(dta.string = c("18 sep. 2016", "29 mei 2014", "7 mrt. 2016"))
oldloc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "dutch")
df$dta.string <- sub("([a-z]{3})(?!\\.)", "\\1.", df$dta.string, perl=TRUE)
as.Date(df$dta.string, format = "%d %h. %Y")
# [1] "2016-09-18" "2014-05-29" "2016-03-07"
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", oldloc)
```

Comment: macOS Sierra isn't letting me change the `LC_TIME` to dutch (i.e. I can't really test it w/o firing up a VM and I'm being lazy), but do you know if it's that locale switching that's enabling `%d` to work without the leading `0` for the day number?

Comment: Hmm using my standard locale `German_Germany.1252`,  `as.Date(c("01 01 2016", "1 1 2016"), "%d %m %Y")` gives the expected result of two dates. I'm on R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03),
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1.

Comment: Very interesting. Even the help on `strptime()` has: _"`%d` Day of the month as decimal number (01–31)."_  which is the same definition as the ISO/IEC 9899:1990 one `strftime()` (which it ultimately uses). I had no idea it was locale dependent. Thx for the extended example/test in that comment.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I'm not sure the leading 0 handling is locale-dependent; `as.Date('1-1-1', '%y-%m-%d')` works fine for me. I suspect it just coerces numeric tokens to numeric so it doesn't matter, but I'm not quite dedicated enough to go dig into the C code to find out.

Comment: Argh! Yep. in `w_strptime_internal()` / `strptime_internal()` R is parsing out the numbers itself. I may poke R-devel mailing list to see if they'd take a PR for to change the `strptime` documentation. I had assumed that it just called the ISO routine directly, but they do quite a bit more processing of the input strings.

Comment: Ok, so that's only _kinda_ true. It's working when there are separators (space, "`-`", "`/`") _but_  `as.Date("4061776", "%d%m%Y")` won't work due  to how R is iterating through the character buffer. With separators there's enough slack and the underlying other buffer format reading/converting R functions are tolerant enough to make it work. I'd caution against relying on the behaviour.